# How to correctly register for push notification in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I have this code to register for push notification on app load, but nothing happened.

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        singleton.deviceToken = nil;
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        var token = deviceToken.description.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.init(charactersIn:"<>"));
        token = token.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "");
        singleton.deviceToken = token;
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegister notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
        if notificationSettings.types == .none { application.registerForRemoteNotifications() }
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Cannot register for push notification. Repeating.")
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications();
    }
```

- I have set breakpoint on all the methods above, but the only method gets called is only `application(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`. All others never gets called.
- The app on my test device never show any request to display push notification.
- I have already request the capability to display push notification on target. It says: [✓] Add the Push Notification to your App ID, and [✓] Add the Push Notification entitlement to your entitlements file.

[image]

- Nothing printed on the console.

What is wrong? And how to fix this? At the very least, I'm expecting `Cannot register for push notification. Repeating.` printed repeatedly on the console if I do fail to register for push notification. But there's nothing on the console too.

PS: I have just updated my Xcode to 8.2.1. But then again, I never tried push notification with my current project until I upgrade to 8.2.1, so I don't know whether the push notification will work or not if I'm working with my older Xcode.

Comment: Have you enabled push notification on Capabilities tab on project settings?

Comment: @Vakas yes I have.

Comment: Also the required configurations on developer portal for push notifications?

Comment: @Vakas yes I have. Please see the updated question.

Comment: kindly check this, you are not imported usernotification framework.http://ashishkakkad.com/2016/09/push-notifications-in-ios-10-swift/

Comment: @karthikeyan oh okay, let me try after this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    self.registerForRemoteNotification(application:application ) // call method to register push notification
    return true
}

//MARK : Push Notification
// add this code in AppDelegate.swift outside of classs
import UserNotifications
extension AppDelegate:UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func registerForRemoteNotification(application: UIApplication) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.delegate = self
            center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert,.sound,.badge], completionHandler: { (complete, error) in
                if let err = error {
                    print(err.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            })
        }
        else {
            let types:UIUserNotificationType = ([.alert, .sound, .badge])
            let settings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types:types, categories:nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }
    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("User Info = ",response.notification.request.content.userInfo)
        completionHandler()

    }
    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        print("User Info = ",notification.request.content.userInfo)
        completionHandler([.alert,.sound,.badge])
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        print(deviceToken)
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
        print("Fail to register for notification : \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active {
            if let dictAps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary {
                if let message = dictAps["alert"] as? String {
                    print(message) // show

                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, wait, I'll get back to you once I try this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> import UserNotifications

framework and add the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate in AppDelegate.swift
Request user permission

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    registerForRemoteNotification()
    return true
}

 func registerForRemoteNotification() {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.delegate = self
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
            if error == nil{
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        }
    }
    else {
          UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.sound, .alert, .badge], categories: nil))
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}

//Getting device token
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
print(deviceTokenString)


}
//In case of error
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {

    print("i am not available in simulator \(error)")

}
//In case if you need to know the permissions granted
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings(){ (setttings) in

        switch setttings.soundSetting{
        case .enabled:

            print("enabled sound setting")

        case .disabled:

            print("setting has been disabled")

        case .notSupported:
            print("something vital went wrong here")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Okay, wait, I'll get back to you once I try this. Thanks!